# Using a PHP Array in a JQuery script

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to use a php array inside some jquery script.  This is what I have:

```
$("#domainPackage").change(function (){
    "use strict";
    var packID;
    var info;
        packID = $("#domainPackage").val();
        info = "<?php echo $package[" + packID + "]['pages'] ?>";
    $("#domainPageLimit").val(info);
});
```

But, it is outputting 
`<?php echo $package[2]['pages'] ?>` into my input box as the value.

What is the correct way of using a PHP array in some jquery?

Thank you

Comment: You should utilize the `json_encode` function in php when dealing with arrays. Makes it much easier to access and iterate through the data. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Are you running the page on a server that has PHP installed, and the page has a .php extension? PHP runs on the server and the result is sent to the user where the JavaScript then runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

This should actually be generating a PHP error which makes me suspect you do not have PHP enabled on this server, or the file extension of the file you are editing is not `.php`.

Once you have fixed that issue, you will need to load the values from the array into the script at run-time, or use AJAX. You cannot interact directly between PHP and jQuery as the PHP runs on the server side before the page is rendered, whereas the jQuery runs in real-time on the client side in the browser.

To load in runtime you could try the following:

```
$("#domainPackage").change(function (){
    var data = JSON.parse(<?=json_encode($package)?>);
    "use strict";
    var packID;
    var info;
    packID = $("#domainPackage").val();
    info = data[packID]['pages'];
    $("#domainPageLimit").val(info);
});
```

Comment: I'm running php 7.  The code I'm using is on an separate js file that is called into my php page with <script></script>.

Comment: You need to put this code directly in the body of the PHP file or the server won't know to process it as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach:

> "The code I'm using is on an separate js file that is called into my php page with <script></script>

is that the script is being processed on the client without ever being seen by PHP, so it cannot process the contents of the `<?php ... ?>` block. Hence your output of `<?php echo $package[2]['pages'] ?>`. To make this work you need to output the data into an array/object in the .php file (the `json_encode` approach suggested by @user1491032 and @coletrain is a good one) and then access that array in your script file i.e.

PHP file:

```
echo "<script>var package = JSON.parse('" . json_encode($package) . "');</script>";
```

JS file:

```
info = package[packID]['pages'];
```

**Update**

As was pointed out by @DavidBélanger, you don't need to use `JSON.parse` if the object is well built, you can just assign the variable directly i.e. in the PHP file:

```
echo "<script>var package = " . json_encode($package) . ";</script>";
```

and in the JS

```
info = package[packID].pages;
```

Comment: No need for the JSON.parse if the object is well built with arrays. You would access it using `package[packID].pages`.